# Pre-load fragments with Android Jetpack Navigation for smooth transitions

Tags: android, android-transitions, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Is it possible to pre-load certain `Fragments` with the [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) from Android Jetpack in order to get smooth transitions?

Without pre-loading I'll never get smooth transitions for the first `navigate()` calls (even on high-end devices). I'm currently using the `app:enterAnim`, `app:exitAnim` etc. tags in my `nav_graph.xml`.

I'm trying to accomplish smooth transitions like in the Telegram app (I think they're pre-loading everything and just animating in the `Fragments` like `Views`).

Is there maybe some hidden XML attribute `app:preload="true"`?

I'm not only asking for full-on answers to my problem - little optimizations are welcome, too!

#### How far I've come:

*anim_nav_enter.xml*

```
<set
    android:duration="200"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <!-- Fade in from the right on enter -->
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="10%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
    </set>
```

*anim_nav_exit.xml*

```
<set
    android:duration="300"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <!-- Fade out on exit -->
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

*anim_nav_pop_enter.xml*

```
<set
    android:duration="200"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <!-- Fade in on pop enter -->
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

*anim_nav_pop_exit.xml*

```
<set
    android:duration="200"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <!-- Fade out to the right on pop exit -->
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="10%" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

*BaseFragment.kt*

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    allowEnterTransitionOverlap = true
    allowReturnTransitionOverlap = true
}

override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
    var animation = super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)
    if (animation == null && nextAnim != 0) {
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, nextAnim)
    }
    if (animation != null) {
        view?.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        animation.setAnimationListener(object : AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                view?.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null)
            }
        })
    }
    return animation
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem here with simple fade_in / fade_out animation, very frustrating.

Comment: Yeah activity animations are smoother. This navigation library is a step back in some ways

Comment: 2 years later I stumbled on the same problem. No solution yet.

Comment: similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60125771/preload-navigation-destination-or-async-navigation-using-android-app-components