# Preload navigation destination or async navigation using Android App Components navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I am using App Component's navigation component. One of my destinations is a more complex form. On it's first call its creation takes around 200 ms. I can clearly notice that, cause the UI blocks for a short, but noticable duration. Each further call (even though the destination fragment is destroyed due to going back) takes only around 90 ms, which feels quite ok.

So, any way to preload the destination fragment?  Or is there any kind of async navigation that does not block the UI? Note that in the creation (`onCreateView`) of the destination fragment, I am doing nothing else than inflating the layout and data binding it. So to my knowledge there's nothing that could be optimized on that side.

Comment: Have you got any solution to it?

Comment: @DeepCodes no, I am now using Compose. Make sure to measure in release mode with R8 optimizations etc, if you have a problem at all with your Views. Anyway, I prefer Compose.